# Abaqus - subroutines: is there a way to know in advance the number of loops the subroutine will perform?

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

I am a new user. Sorry if this question seems silly:
Is there a way to know in advance the number of loops the subroutine will perform?
(The subroutines can be USDFLD, VUMAT or UMAT, for example)

I am working with the USDFLD subroutine. I checked all the subroutine variables doing "(write (*,*), 'variable'") looking into the results on the .log file, but I could not find a variable that correlates directly to the number of total loops the subroutine perform.

Comment: Could not explain what you mean by "number of loops"? Do you mean "number of iterations"?

Comment: Also note that this is a general programming group. Very few will know what what Abaqus is, and even fewer will know about USDFLD, VUMAT or UMAT. If you can put your question in less abaqus specific form you are much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: thanks.
In Abaqus, which is a finite element software, the user has the option to work implementing a subroutine code (Fortran) that is linked to the software and allows it to perform custom tasks that would not be possible by using the software itself. 
In this context, a subroutine works such as a loop for (DO in fortran). 
"Number of loops" means how many iterations there will be in this loop, for example in a loop `DO i=1,10  (...)  END DO`  there will be 10 loops, since the counter `i` (which is an integer) will assume values from 1 to 10.
USDFLD, VUMAT or UMAT are user subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general there is no way for a calling subroutine by itself to know how many times it will be called.

However, I *guess* that some types of routines will be called in predictable ways. For example, if you implement a custom routine to compute some material property, it might get computed for each cell for each iteration of the solve. So if the number of cells and requested number of iterations are available, then you may be able to compute it.